# Have the nayanar shaiva saints of Tamil nadu wrote poems on lord shiva's sons?

Tags: history, ganesha, shaiva-siddhanta, tamil, nayanar

Is there mention of Lord ganesha in the poems of nayanars?
I know that shankaracharya wrote ganesha bhujangam and ganesh panchratna but have nayanars wrote about family of Lord shiva?